# Tracking all the request and response in Chrome Devtools with Selenium 4

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

This one is not tracking xhr type

```
devTools = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(),Optional.empty()));
```